# Cannot open software sources after removing a PPA

Tags: software-sources

After deleting a ppa entry in the sources.list file, I was not able to open the software sources application. Opening the software centre is fine.  I tried running gksudo software-properties-gtk and got the follwong message:

```
 SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 580, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a "
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template
```

Would appreciate if you can let me know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick thing to do is remove and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove --purge software-properties-gtk

sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
```

The next thing I would do if that didn't work:

Backup the file

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py.backup
```

Then remove it

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py
```

do this to other offending files and try again

Comment: Have done the remove and reinstall as suggested but software sources still not opening up

Comment: after you removed the PPA did you run an update? as in `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Yes, I did. Also tried to open software sources from software centre but no success.

Comment: After removing the offending files, do I need to reinstall software-properties-gtk